# Creating problems of form "$a_1l_1^n+\ldots + a_k l_k^n$ is always divisible by $2023$"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Say you're writing home assignments for future freshman-year students of next year. Teaching about induction, question such as "prove that $2^{n+1} + 5^n$ is divisible by $3$ for every natural $n$" appear frequently.

> Are there any interesting ways of creating such problems, easily proven by induction, but with the given expression being divisible by $2023$?

Say we wish to concentrate on problems of form "$f(n) = a_1l_1^n+\ldots + a_k l_k^n$ is always divisible by $m=2023$, for each $n \in \Bbb{N}$" for natural numbers $l_1 < \ldots < l_k$ and some integers $a_1 ,\ldots , a_k$. Let's assume we were able to choose them in a way s.t. $f(0) = 0$ (as an induction base). The inductive step, assuming $f(n)$ is divisible by 2023, is of form

$$
\begin{align}
f(n+1)   &=  a_1 l_1 l_1^n + a_2 l_2 l_2^n + \ldots + a_k l_k l_k^n \\
         &=  l_1 f(n) + a_2 (l_2-l_1) l_2^n + \ldots + a_k (l_k-l_1) l_k^n \\
         &\equiv a_2 (l_2-l_1) l_2^n + \ldots + a_k (l_k-l_1) l_k^n  ~\operatorname{mod} (2023).
\end{align}
$$
This reduces the problem in "one step", into a problem with $2(n-1)$ coefficients to choose. As $2023=17\cdot 17\cdot 7 = 119 \cdot 7$, by taking $k=2, a_2 = 119$ and $l_2 - l_1 =17$, we can make the expression above divisible by $2023$. This gives, for example, the sequence $f(n) = 119\cdot {22}^{n+1}-2618\cdot 5^n$.

> Are there more elegant ways of creating such sequences? Or, for example, sequences of form $a\cdot p^n + b \cdot n + c$ that are divisible by $2023$?

Comment: I think this is already a very elegant method ! An improvement would be to reduce $2618$ mod $2023$

Comment: The given example however is not really that interesting. Since the expression can be written as $$2618(22^n-5^n)$$ and we have $7\cdot 17\mid 2618$ , we only have to show $17\mid 22^n-5^n$ which is obvious if we reduce $22$ mod $17$.